# vimeo advanced api for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, vimeo

[image]

I have used OA consumer class in my app  and  while trying to run it i got this error and i dint understand the problem. i have added -ObjC to other linker flags also. i have searched google but dint find any related to this. I have disabled the arc and do i need to add any linker flags or is there any other problem.[image: This is my code]

can you please tell me whether there is an error in code or do i have to change the linker settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are linker errors -- it's finding the headers just fine, but the library is missing at link time. Make sure the OA library is in the **Linked Frameworks and Libraries** list for your target.

Comment: Thanks. I solved the error by checking the target membership of the file in utilities->file inspector.

Answer (score 0):

I removed this error after lots of trails, the problem in my case is the corefoundation framework is corrupted, it has shown a small question mark on it, after i carefully read the exception, it says that some files are missing from the corefoundation framework, then i removed the framework and copied a new one from another project then the errors gone.

Note: while you are removing any file, don't just remove references , move it to trash, other wise the Xcode may give you a error file already exist and cannot be copied.